# Framework Menu own error

Tags: php, menu, frameworks

I create an MVC framework and I have a problem with links menu in August must show your different for the user and the person does not zalogoanej. And now I do not like to do it of the idea, I would like to view the files, you could enter something like this:
"echo $ this-> menu-> left (link text)," but now I do not know how to check the permissions that are stored in the session username

Diagram:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg1UP.png

Answer (score 0):

Okay, by drawing a diagram in the middle of the night I had no idea that he himself replied to the question:)